# Access django session and user asynch/in different (unix) process

Tags: django, tornado

I'd like to integrate a streamlit application - streamlit is based on tornado - into django via an `<iframe>`, while ensuring that streamlit requests only go through if there is an authenticated user in django running on the same domain - e.g. via nginx or both running on different ports.

However, I'm experiencing issues with asynch-ness. I've set `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` as a quick fix, but obviously don't get warm from database corruption due to concurrent access. So far I'm protecting myself from that by adding read-only access to the database, but can image particular django classes, e.g. the SessionStore, also aren't thread safe (although probably process safe?).

Is there a safe way to do 'read-only' authentication via django in other wsgi(-ish) applications, like tornado?

This is the tornado script, running next to it any django application with user authentication of whatever sort (default, saml2, etc). The `django_authentication_middleware` extracts the appropriate session id from the cookies and passes this the django's `get_user` function to then verify authentication. `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should be set as for the django application.

To get the error, disable `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE`.

```py
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE'] = 'true'

import asyncio
from importlib import import_module
from typing import Optional, Awaitable

import django
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import get_user

import tornado.web
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer


SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore


class UnauthorizedHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def data_received(self, chunk: bytes) -> Optional[Awaitable[None]]:
        pass

    def prepare(self):
        return self.send_error(401)


class AuthorizedHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def data_received(self, chunk: bytes) -> Optional[Awaitable[None]]:
        pass

    def get(self):
        return self.write("authorized")


def get_user_from_django(request):
    session_key = request.cookies.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
    if session_key is None:
        return None
    session_key = session_key.value
    django_request = HttpRequest()
    django_request.session = SessionStore(session_key)
    return get_user(django_request)


def django_authentication_middleware(request):
    global unauthorized_application, authorized_application
    user = get_user_from_django(request)
    
    if user is not None and user.is_authenticated:
        return authorized_application(request)
    else:
        return unauthorized_application(request)



unauthorized_application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r".*", UnauthorizedHandler),
])
authorized_application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r".*", AuthorizedHandler),
])




async def main():
    server = HTTPServer(django_authentication_middleware)
    server.listen(8888)
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I'd use Redis to keep a copy of Django sessions (because Redis is fast). So, whenever a user logs in through Django, you also put that session id in a Redis db; and when the user logs out, you delete that session key from Redis as well. On the Tornado side, just connect to the Redis db and check if the session id is present or not. There are some async clients for Redis for Python, so you can query Redis without blocking Tornado's event loop. This will give you much better performance than what you're doing currently.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good work-around. Although I'd be afraid writing authentication code myself, and ending up doing something that's vulnerable. I'd strongly prefer using django's own methods to authenticate.